# let $f(x)$ be rational non constant polynomial and $f\circ f(x)=3f(x)^4-1$ then find the $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, functional-equations

let $f(x)$ be rational non constant polynomial and $f\circ f(x)=3f(x)^4-1$
then find the $f(x)$ .

My Try :

$$f(f(x))=3f(x)^4-1$$

Let $f(x)=ax^n+g(x)$ so :

$$a(ax^n+g(x))^n+g(ax^n+g(x))=3(ax^n+g(x))^4-1$$

$$a^2x^{n^2}+h(x)+k(x)=3ax^{4n}+l(x)-1$$

$$3ax^{4n}-a^2x^{n^2}-1=h(x)+k(x)-l(x)$$

Now what ?

Comment: Formatting note:  you can get the composition symbol by "\circ"

Comment: Math note:  just comparing degrees, you want $n^2=4n$, so you know what $n$ is.

Comment: @lulu why $n^2=4n $ ?

Comment: Another hint: is there one particular polynomial that you might guess would be a solution? After that, you just need to check that it's the only one.

Comment: *Hint.* If you identify $f$ with the polynomial function $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$, then for any $y \in \{ f(x) : x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$, we have $f(y) = 3y^4 - 1$. What can you say from this?

Comment: The degree of $f\circ f$ is $n^2$.  The degree of $f^4$ is $4n$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $3f(x)^4 - 1 = g\circ f(x)$, where $g(x) = 3x^4 - 1$. So $f = g$, at least, is a solution.

Now, if $f$ is a solution, we need to show that $f(x) = g(x)$. But note that $f \circ f(x) = g\circ f(x)$ for all $x$, so $(g - f) \circ f(x) = 0$, so $g - f$ is zero on the image of $f$, which, since $f$ is non-constant, contains some interval $(a,b)$, hence $g - f$ is everywhere zero, so $f = g$ is the only solution.

Comment: +1 This is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The highest degree terms on each side of what you have are:

$a_n^{n+1}x^{n^2}  = 3a_n^4x^{4n}$

$n^2 = 4n\\ n = 4\\ a_4^5 = 3a_4^4\\
a_4 = 3$

But, there is a more direct approach.

$f(f(x)) = 3(f(x))^4 - 1$

Replace the $f(x)$ with $u$ everywhere we see it.

$f(u) = 3u^4 - 1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that, because I think that you supposed deg $g(x)\leq n-1$, from
$$
a_n(a_n x^n+g(x))^n+g(a_n x^n+g(x))=
3(a_n x^n+g(x))^4-1$$
the degree of the LHS is $n^2$, while on the other hand the degree of the RHS is $4n$. This is an equality between two polynomials, hence their degree must be the same. Then $n=4$. Moreover the two polynomials must have the same leading coefficient. The coefficient of $x^{16}$ in the LHS is $a_4^{5}$, while the coefficient in the RHS is $3a_4^{4}$, hence $a_4=3$.
Now I think that you have to put $f(x)=3x^4+\sum_{i=0}^{3} a_i x^i $ in the equation and compute